# Leaflet: Subsequent map.locate() times out if option "watch" is set to "true"

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet

I'm struggling to resolve the problem where leaflet's map.locate() will at first correctly raises the "locationfound" event, but each subsequent call will timeout/freeze no matter what I do.

If the "watch" is set to false, the call "map.locate(options)" works properly.

Steps to reproduce:

- open the link above,
- click the geolocate button once and wait,
- map will zoom to the geolocated location,
- pan the map,
- click the geolocate btn again,
- watch it fail (in console)

Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
function geolocateMe() {

      if (!registered) {
        map.on("locationfound", cb);
        map.on("locationerror", eb);
        registered = true;
      }

      map.locate({
        watch: true,
        setView: true
      });
    }
```

Seet the plunker here [Leaflet locate issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z8rcJryFkIVj4vjGEzOX?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, one needs to read the geolocation API properly here [Geolocation API- watchPosition()](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#watch-position)

As the timeout and maximumAge is crucial. Basically, and that's what I don't like, if you provide timeout and maximumAge, then if the location doesn't update within the timeout value, the "locationerror" is thrown with the timeout error. I reckon that is misleading, there should be "no-update-within" event which would be easier to comprehend.

Basically if you don't provide the timeout, then each request for the position will look into the cached position, if this is older than maximumAge since the last update, it will immediately trigger a new position acquire from the device.

```
var geo_options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  maximumAge: 60000
    //timeout           : 1000
};
```

Just play around it in another plunker that uses the basic geolocation api -> [enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/KCYVAIQ1irRVDB3xFALX)

Hope that helps. I was just confused why I was getting all the timeout messages and no location. Now I understand it.